# Setting $_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER'] for redirection after login?

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I'm trying to redirect people to the page they came from after they login.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is unreliable so what do you think of me setting `$_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER']` to the page they were on before they get directed to the login page in the first place?

I'm building an ajaxy-fadey-pretty-poncy-looking type app with rewritten URLS so don't want to use something ugly like the querystring to send data.

Any thoughts? Should I use `$_POST`s instead (bit of a pain)?

Comment: "ajaxy-fadey-pretty-poncy-looking type app". lol. I hope your employer doesn't view it that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER']` is generally a bad idea because it's not the HTTP Referrer so the name is misleading which is bad.

You can however solve your problem by using `$_SESSION` as well as you could with any other information you add to the login query, like a hidden form field `$_POST` or a query info parameter `$_GET`.

Take care that when you do the redirect, the value is properly encoded, a valid URI and in a valid context, e.g. only redirecting to your site (not some other site).

Answer (score 2):

It is a good approach - many frameworks offer an implementation like that (symfony 1.4 f.e. `$this->getUser()->setReferer($url);`. You could also choose to keep it as a parameter in your `$_GET` (`login.html?from=somepage`). Both are very common. A third possible solution is that you display the login box on the same URL so that you won't need to do any redirect-logic.